# SWIG TCL Static Linking

Tags: tcl, swig, static-linking

I am trying to use SWIG to generate wrappers for some of my C++ function calls.

Also, I am trying to do build my own TCL shell so I need to static link the generated SWIG libraries. I have my own main function with a `Tcl_AppInit` call where I do some prior setup.

To do this what function should I include in my program's `Tcl_AppInit` call? I found that `SWIG_init` is not the right function. I even tried `Cell_Init` where cell is the name of the class in my code, but that doesn't help either.

How do I static link SWIG object files with my own main function and `Tcl_Appinit` call?

Currently when I use the following command to link my executabel I get the following error:

```
g++ -o bin/icde src/core/*.o src/read/*.o src/swig/*.o src/icde/*.o -ltk -ltcl
```

I get the following error:

```
src/icde/main.o: In function `AppInit(Tcl_Interp*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0xa9): undefined reference to `Cell_Init(Tcl_Interp*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I checked the src/swig/cell.o file which has the Cell_Init function or not using objdump:

```
~> objdump -d src/swig/cell.o | grep Cell_Init
00006461 <Cell_Init>:
    646c:       75 0a                   jne    6478 <Cell_Init+0x17>
```

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong while linking.

------------------- UPDATE ----------------------------

I found that including the swig/swig.cxx file directly in the main file which calls the Tcl_AppInit function resolves the linking issue. Is there a reason for this.

Isn't it possible to create and seprately link the swig file and the file with the main function?

Comment: In response to your update, it's possible but you've got one of the easiest methods. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In general, with SWIG you'll end up with a bunch of generated source files that you compile. The normal thing you do then is package them up into a shared library (with appropriate bound dependencies on other shared libraries) that can be imported into a Tcl runtime with the [`load`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/load.htm) command.

But you don't want that this time. Instead, you want the object files that you would use to make that shared lib, and you want to include them in the instructions to build an executable along with the object file that holds your `main` and [`Tcl_AppInit`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/AppInit.htm). You also need to make sure that when linking your main executable that you make *it* dependent on those external shared libraries; executable building requires that you satisfy all dependencies and make all symbols be bound to their definitions. (You can use a static library to make this easier: it combines a bunch of object files into one file. There's very little difference to just using the object files from it though; in particular, static libraries aren't bound to their dependencies.)

Finally, you *do* want to include a call to `Cell_Init` in your `Tcl_AppInit`. That's the right place to put it (well, as long as you're not arranging for the package to be loaded into sub-interpreters). If it was failing before, that was because you'd got your linking wrong. (Tip: linkers work best when objects and libraries on the link line only depend on things *later* on the link line. Getting the link order right is a bit of a black art when you've got a complex build!)

Comment: OK, there's more complexity I've not covered, such as weakly bound symbols and the non-trivial definition of “binding”, but you can ignore that for now. Understanding those parts won't help you make your code link and work!

Comment: I did everything you mentioned. I even check the object files to make sure the CellInit function calls exists using the objdump command. I have added link command in the above post. Could you let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Hmm, could be that it needs linking in a C++-understanding way. My knowledge of C++ practicalities is very shaky (Tcl itself is done in pure C for good reason). If you've found something that works, go with that!

Comment: Putting some `extern "C"` in the right places might fix things, if its due to name mangling.